# If a group and a groupoid have the same profinite completions, can anything be said about them?

Tags: abstract-algebra, topological-groups, formal-completions

Pretty much what I ask in the title. Suppose $\mathbb{G}$ is a group and $\mathcal{G}$ is a groupoid. Consider their profinite completions $\overline{\mathbb{G}}$ and $\overline{\mathcal{G}}$.

If the completions give the same group, then is it possible to say anything about the relationship between $\mathbb{G}$ and $\mathcal{G}$ ?

Comment: How does it make sense to ask for equality here? What common place do these naturally live?

Comment: Oh God, I was writing another question and got confused, sorry. No, I definitely did not mean strict equality, I will edit the question.

Comment: What is your definition of the profinite completion of a groupoid?  What does it mean for the completions to "give the same group"?  Is $\mathcal{G}$ supposed to be connected?